# Converting from a 32-bit two's complement to decimal using java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble finding a way to convert from a 32-bit two's complement binary number to a decimal in java. I either get an overflow error or the number comes out nonnegative when it should be negative.

```
String bin = "11111111111111111111111111111110";
long foo = Long.parseLong(bin);
System.out.println(foo);
```

This is one of the things I tried and I was thinking I needed to use long because it can hold up to 64-bits. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: A 32-bit two's complement binary number is an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the base, or radix, of two if you want to parse a binary value.

```
long foo = Long.parseLong(bin, 2);
```

You can see an example on the [Java doc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String,%20int)):

> `parseLong("1100110", 2)` returns `102L`.

Without the radix, it uses base-10, and `1032` won't fit into a `long`.

Keep in mind that, for a 32-character bit string, this will give you the *unsigned* variant. If you want the signed variant in a `long`, you can use:

```
if (foo > 0x7fffffffL) foo = -(0x100000000L - foo);
```

afterwards to adjust it

Or you can forcefully cast it to an integer if that's suitable:

```
int foo = (int)Long.parseLong(bin,2);
```

The requirement that `Integer.parseInt()` be given a *signed* number means that it's unsuitable as-is for 32-character binary strings with a leftmost 1-bit.

Answer (score 0):

`radix` is the base of the used numbering system.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bits = (int) Long.parseLong("11111111111111111111111111111110", 2);
        System.out.println(bits);
    }
```

**output**

```
-2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct - you need to use "Long" in this case.

Since you're doing twos complement (not ones complement), you can use "parseLong()" with a radix of "2":

```
public class X {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    String bin = "11111111111111111111111111111110";
    int i = (int)Long.parseLong(bin, 2);
    System.out.println("parseInt(" + bin + ", 2)=" + i);
  }

}
// Output:
parseInt(11111111111111111111111111111110, 2)=-2
```